# One of these most intelligent students whose example (is/are) being

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, subject-verb-agreement, grammatical-number

Please help me with

> One of these most intelligent students whose example (is/are) being followed (is/are) David. ([question 42](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6mdh.jpg))

I have checked its answer, but I still don't understand it.

The correct answer is "is-is". Why is the first blank "is" and not "are"?

Comment: Please type any relevant text into your question, don't link or post images of text. Not everybody can read the text in images. I've fixed this question for you.

Answer (score 1):

This is a horrid sentence of English. It has an overly long subject and so is very hard for anyone to understand.  Don't write like this!

Consider these examples

> One of the cats whose tails are long
>
> One of the cats, whose tail is long
>
> One of the boys whose school is big
>
> One of the boys whose schools are big.
>
> One of the boys, whose school is big.

The agreement in your sentence should be with the word "example" and not with the word students.

The use of the word "most" is odd, it seems to be being used an intensifier, and not as an indicator of a superlative.  The word "most" here means "very" and not "the most".